# Equating to zero as many of the highly linearly dependent entities as possible

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, symbolic-computation

I have $7$ variables $x_1$, ..., $x_7$ and a bunch of their linear combinations; specifically, denoting $s=x_1+...+x_7$, these combinations are $s-5(x_i+x_j)$, $1\leqslant i<j\leqslant7$ and  $2s-5(x_i+x_j+x_k)$, $1\leqslant i<j<k\leqslant7$. So altogether (counting each $x_i$ and $s$) I have $64$ expressions. I want to choose $x_1$, ..., $x_7$ arbitrarily in such a way that as many of these $64$ expressions as possible become zero, **but not all of them**.

Which largest number of zeroes can I achieve and how to do it?

Obviously there must be some general method; but then again, maybe for this specific set of expressions I can do better than by some general method, I don't know. And I do not know that general method anyway.

So far I can do 32 zeroes, by putting $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=1$ and $x_6=x_7=0$. Can one do better?

Comment: Then what about just one variable nonzero? Say $x_1=1$ and $x_2=\cdots =x_7=0$. You could just write a program with Gauss elimination.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $x_1=1$ and $x_2=\cdots=x_7=0$ gives only $6$ zeroes out of $64$

Comment: @DietrichBurde What kind of program do you suggest? I tried to equate to zero one by one, but it seems to depend on the order in which I take them: in most attempts it stops at a relatively small number of zeros since adding one more constraint forces all of them to become zero.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think it is something like a polytope with facets having various numbers of vertices, and one has to find a facet with largest number of vertices.